# How do you fix the grub rescue

Tags: grubrescue

I deleted the Ubuntu partition via Windows and was going to use an USB to re download and install it. But when I restarted the computer the unknown file system and grub rescue screen came up.

Now, I can't even start up Windows. I'm just stuck on the grub rescue screen and I have no idea how to fix it and I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: If you have a Windows Boot disk/CD you can try mending windows, then you can start on the Ubuntu side of things. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Super Grub2 Disk` to repair the boot section (in case that you deleted or corrupted `grub` when you deleted Ubuntu partition) as the description specifies:

> The primary purpose of Super GRUB2 Disk is to help you boot into an OS
>   whose bootloader is broken. Second, and almost as important, is to be
>   a tool to learn more about GRUB2 and the booting process.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

Else, you can use a Windows Repair Disk if something more is broken in the Windows boot sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Use a Windows Repair Disk to restore MBR.
- Use a LiveUSB of Ubuntu to install it again.

If you do not have any of them but there is another computer available, you may use that one to create a Windows Repair disk or an Ubuntu LiveUSB (or both).

Good luck.